Is "say they" correct?
English is not my first language.
The text below is a translation of the Quran by Ahmed Ali :

And when it is said unto them, "Follow ye what God hath sent down", say they, "Nay! Follow we that on which found we our fathers."

What is the word order or sentence structure used here? The last part is hard to understand. And is "say they" an old-fashioned way of saying "they say" ?

Other translations show ... "they answer, nay,"

@alphabet Now that you mentioned this , I wanted to ask why almost most of the news texts have this word order? For example : a quote and then at the ending  "... Said Mr president" . What is this called grammatically ? Thank you.

@YosefBaskin Thank you. And what do you think about the last part : "Follow we that on which found we our fathers."

Hard to follow. Again, there are less stiff (and less cryptic) versions: "even if their fathers did not understand anything and were not guided."

The use of said John after a quote is far less unusual than that of say/said they. It's at best highly poetic / archaic.

@Mike It's called quotative inversion, as the answer to that question states. It tends to be found in formal or literary contexts; it's not very common in casual speech.

@YosefBaskin it is actually. But what is style in this text ? It Looks like a poem to me .

It's an archaic style of English. When you see words like "ye" and "thou", it's likely to be at least 300 years old. There are a few places where this dialect persists (e.g. Pennsylvania Dutch, parts of Scotland), but it's mostly obsolete.

This is a heavy literal translation from Arabic, but it is not using "implies the narrator" ordering. Semitic languages rely less than English on word order. By putting 'say' first, it's like daring to say. If you compare KJV to the Hebrew, you'd see one is regal and graceful; one is lordly, almost pompous. One says God is a soldier; one translates word for word to say God is a man of war. One says human; one says Son of Adam.
